# Acces denied MariaDB Amazon-rds instance RMySQL and OBDC (windows)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds, rmysql

I'm trying to connect R with my MariaDB instance (10.0 - Amazon RDS). Connection works fine in HeidiSQL. Both in R and ODBC drivers installation (direct and indirect), next error is prompted:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My account is the admin account of this instance, I used the following code:

```
library(RMySQL)

mySqlCreds <- list(dbhostname = "dbname.rds.amazonaws.com" , dbname="dbnamefull"                 , username = "user",pass = "secret", port = 3306) 

drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")

dbConnect(drv, host=mySqlCreds$dbhostname, dbname=mySqlCreds$dbname, user=mySqlCreds$username, password=mySqlCreds$pass, port = mySqlCreds$port)
```

Same problem while connecting an ODBC driver in Windows to this instance- finds database, but again no access. Even after modifying instance parameter groups in aws console, log_bin_trust_function_creators to 1, and rebooting the database.

If you know how to solve this issue, please let me know! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you paste the security group for your Maria DB RDS?

Comment: thanks. Standard security group : rds-launch-wizard, vpc-01c2f968, Created from the RDS Management Console. Inbound rules are three IPadresses of MySQL/Aurora Type with TCP protocol and port 3306, I didnt change the outbound rules (all traffic with destination ip 0.0.0.0/0). After assigning these inbound rules I can access my mariadb instance via HeidiSQL from these three places.

Comment: When do you get that error? What query do you run?

Comment: Via every type of SQL program I granted access. ButI would like to substract the data from my datawarehouse such that it can directly be used for modeling. Ran a script in R, using RMySQL, see above. and seperately creating an ODBC connection with Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator. Seems like I have a problem with the VPC settings of amazon? Or admin settings - from my account I dont have the premission to write tables and cant change it?

Comment: Your error says user'@'localhost why is is showing local host it should show the RDS host name?